# How to see a certain view when clicking a button in backbone

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, marionette

The following code is supposed to render one of three views...either firstRegion, secondRegion or thirdRegion, by clicking on the button in the code...

```
    const pressButton1 = () => {

const MyView = Mn.View.extend({
  template: _.template('<div><input type="button" value="Click me to see Component 1" onclick="pressButton1()" id="first-region" /></div>'),
  regions: {
    firstRegion: '#first-region',
    secondRegion: '#second-region',
    thirdRegion: '#third-region',
  }
});

const myView = new MyView();
myView.render();
$('body').append(myView.$el);

let loadView = require('./components/cmp1/view').default
console.log(loadView)
myView.getRegion('firstRegion').show(new loadView())

//$(document).foundation();

};

pressButton1();
```

So I've changed the above but I'm getting 'Uncaught ReferenceError: pressButton1 is not defined at HTMLInputElement.onclick'

How can this be defined?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Marionette (through its extension of Backbone) has an [events hash](https://marionettejs.com/docs/master/marionette.view.html#view-events) for each view, which binds DOM events from it's `el` and template. In other words, no onclick needs to be defined in the template html.
Each view also has a [showChildView function](https://marionettejs.com/docs/master/marionette.view.html#showing-a-view) which accepts a region and view, and is being used in the snippet below to show the child views.

```js
const Component1 = Mn.View.extend({
  template: _.template('Template for Component 1')
});
const Component2 = Mn.View.extend({
  template: _.template('Template for Component 2')
});
const Component3 = Mn.View.extend({
  template: _.template('Template for Component 3')
});

const MyView = Mn.View.extend({
  template: _.template('<div><input type="button" value="Click me to see Component 1"  id="first-region-button" /></div><div id="first-region"></div>' +
    '<div><input type="button" value="Click me to see Component 2"  id="second-region-button" /></div><div id="second-region"></div>' +
    '<div><input type="button" value="Click me to see Component 3"  id="third-region-button" /></div><div id="third-region"></div>'),
  regions: {
    firstRegion: '#first-region',
    secondRegion: '#second-region',
    thirdRegion: '#third-region',
  },
  ui: {
    component1Button: 'input#first-region-button',
    component2Button: 'input#second-region-button',
    component3Button: 'input#third-region-button'
  },
  events: {
    'click @ui.component1Button': function() {
      this.showChildView('firstRegion', new Component1())
    },
    'click @ui.component2Button': function() {
      this.showChildView('secondRegion', new Component2())
    },
    'click @ui.component3Button': function() {
      this.showChildView('thirdRegion', new Component3())
    }
  }
});

const myView = new MyView();
myView.render();
$('body').append(myView.$el);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.2/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.8.3/underscore-min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/backbone.js/1.3.3/backbone-min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/backbone.radio/2.0.0/backbone.radio.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/backbone.marionette/3.5.1/backbone.marionette.js"></script>
```